# Forms authentication while Anonymous authentication disabled

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, iis-8.5

I configured a web application to use Form authentication.  When open Login page I got the following error:-

```
Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.
```

It works fine when enable Anonymous Authentication.  I need to understand why?  Is that normal behavior?

Comment: http://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication/

Comment: Show us your web.config authentication section and explain how you configured authentication within IIS.